# Lubuntu and remote desktop

Tags: lubuntu, remote-desktop

I have a SSH address that I connect through command line, but I would like to have a GUI option to make my work easier. So is it possible to connect through ssh using remote desktop on Lubuntu 11.10? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Both the steps to setup a remote desktop and use it over SSH is explained on the [remote desktop wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/RemoteDesktop).